# how to add css on click and remove it when they click close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to use the below CSS on click using javascript or jquery. Does anyone know how to do it?

```
#outer-wrapper {width:100%;max-width:1000px;margin:0 auto;padding:0;text-align:left;float:none;background-position:center!important;}
#post-wrapper {width:100%;max-width:1000px;margin:0 auto;text-align:left;float:none;background-position:center!important;}
.post-body,.post{background-position:center!important;}
#blog1,#artikel,.blog-posts{background-position:center!important;}
.banner,#footer-wrapper,#comments,#sidebar-wrapper,#header-wrapper,#menu-wrapper {display:none;margin-top:0;margin:0;}
.post-inner {padding:0 0 0 0;margin:20px auto;}
```

My aim is when the user clicks the HTML element the CSS should be applied to that and when he clicks close button the CSS should be removed from the element.

Comment: You can use Javascript / JQuery to do this for you, read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_addclass.asp What have you tried yet yourself?

Comment: have you search the web?

Comment: Use jQuery `addClass()` / `removeClass()` Read about it here http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: @KevinVoorn i wan to add and remove css on click but it only shows how to add css on click

Comment: @Santo007 You can use removeClass() to do this

Comment: @KevinVoorn I want the complete answer please since i am a beginner in js and jquery

Comment: This website is not a place where you can ask others to do your work. Search on Google for similar answers as there are a lot of tutorials online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
   <button id="start">Start</button> 
     <button id="close">Close</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('#start').click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('start');

    });

$('#close').click(function () {
        $('#start').removeClass('start');

    });
```

**CSS**

```
.start
{
// css style here
}
```

Comment: can i use css as below.                                              .start{ all my css posted in question in this class 
}

Comment: Yes you can add styles when clicked.

Comment: But this is not working i tried this

Comment: @Santo007 dont worry. You have to add dependencies of latest Jquery. <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> paste this on your <head>. Good luck.

Comment: I have already added it but it doesn't work you can see it on my demo blog http://uyhbnerhgdi.blogspot.in/2014/12/another-post.html

Comment: Sorry i had mistake upadte with this will work.

$('#start').removeClass('start'); I have updated my answer too. Let me know it works.

Comment: Thanks this js works fine but we cannot add classes inside a class as you said to add css inside .start{ css }.We can only add properties but not add classes

Answer (score 0):

You need [element.classList - Web API Interfaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList)
if you want to use different buttons for that try this

```js
function addclass() {
  mydiv.classList.add("visible");
}

function removeclass() {
  mydiv.classList.remove("visible");
}

var addButton = document.querySelector(".addButton"),
    removeButton = document.querySelector(".removeButton"),
    mydiv = document.querySelector(".mydiv");


addButton.addEventListener("click", addclass, false);
removeButton.addEventListener("click", removeclass, false);
```

```css
.mydiv{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  margin: 20px auto
}

.visible{
  opacity: .1;
}
```

```html
<div class=mydiv ></div>
<button class=addButton>Add Class<button>
<button class=removeButton>Remove Class<button>
```

to just toggle it

```
var div = document.querySelector(".mydiv");
// if visible is set remove it, otherwise add it
div.classList.toggle("visible");
```

a full example on how to use is :

```js
 
function modifyopacity() {
  this.classList.toggle("visible");
}
 
var div = document.querySelector(".mydiv");
div.addEventListener("click", modifyopacity, false);
```

```css
.mydiv{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  margin: 20px auto
}

.visible{
    opacity: .1;
}
```

```html
<div class=mydiv ></div>
```

Comment: No how can the above js uses my css i posted in the question

Comment: @Santo007  Check the update with opacity